# Как вернуть MemoryStream из функции?

Tags: c#, linux, .net, windows

У меня есть метод, который возвращает MemoryStream. Так получается, что когда я вызываю этот метод на Windows, то он работает корректно и возвращает данные, записанные в MemoryStream. Однако, если я вызываю этот метод на Linux, то метод возвращает пустой Stream. С чем это может быть связано? (Используется .NET Core)

```
public async Task<Stream> GetInfo()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    bool bytesReceived = false;

    do
    {
        byte[] buffer = await storage.ReadAsync();

        await ms.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        bytesReceived = buffer.Length != 0;
    }
    while(bytesReceived);

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return ms;
}
```

Вот место откуда вызывается этот метод:

```
public async Task ReadData()
{
    var info = await GetInfo();

    var reader = new StreamReader(info);

    var dataString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine(dataString);
}
```

Вот метод ReadAsync:

```
public async Task<byte[]> ReadAsync()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10];

    await activeStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: А что такое storage.ReadAsync? У вас возможно нет прав на чтение данного ресурса.

Comment: Проблема за пределами показанного кода - где-то здесь `await storage.ReadAsync()`.

Comment: Проверяется просто. Запишите явно какую-нибудь информацию, строку или ещё чего там

Comment: activeStream это System.IO.Stream в методе ReadAsync. Член класса storage

Comment: Ну, все просто, ваш `activeStream` пустой.

Comment: `Task<byte> ReadAsync()` не скомпилируется, быть может `Task<byte[]> ReadAsync()`? Как вы вообще смогли запустить этот код? Кстати, а почему вы таким странным образм копируете данные из потока в поток? Почему не просто `.CopyToAsync()`?

Comment: Согласен, опечатался, там Task<byte[]> ReadAsync()

Comment: Насчёт того, что activeStream пустой. Нужно будет ещё раз проверить, хотя я вроде добавлял логи, и массив после чтения не был пуст

Comment: Зачем кстати вообще копирование? Почему бы не читать данные напрямую из потока источника?

Comment: Метод ReadAsync это упрощённый вариант, на самом деле в этом методе идёт обращение к серверу, и через сокеты загружаются данные

Comment: Ваня исключите проблему Memory Stream. И дальше смотрите что у вас и где

Comment: Логируйте и смотрите что где пришло ушло

Comment: Так выкладывали бы код как есть, и сразу бы стало понятно. Возможно на момент чтения данные еще посто не приехали. И вы получаете пустой Stream. Выкладывайте код как есть. Ваше упрощение только все усложняет.

Comment: Кстати, если у вас `NetworkStream`, и вы хотите его распараллелить на несколько потребителей, вот я писал [такую штуковину](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/244314/226545). Код из вопроса у меня в проде работает исправно. Копируемый поток здесь блокируется потоком-источником до тех пор, пока данные не приедут.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема кроется в другом месте. И связана она со storage. Это Linux там нужно следить за доступом, а MemoryStream проверяется легко.

Попробуйте так чтоб исключить вашу проблему.

```
public async Task<Stream> GetInfo()

{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    bool bytesReceived = false;

    do
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world!!!!");

        await ms.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        bytesReceived = buffer.Length != 0;
    }
    while(bytesReceived);

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо. Нашел решение для моего случая. Ситуация была такая, что метод висел на ожидании получения данных от метода ReadAsync. Поэтому как я думал в консоль ничего не выводилось. А на самом деле висело в цикле.

```
public async Task<Stream> GetInfo()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 

    bool bytesReceived = false; 

    do 
    { 
        Task<byte[]> buffer = await storage.ReadAsync(); 

        await ms.WriteAsync(buffer.Result, 0, buffer.Result.Length); 

        bytesReceived = buffer.Result.Length != 0; 
    } 
    while(bytesReceived); 

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return ms; 
}
```